# Java jasper reports list as data source

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to make list object as my data source, can you tell me for `.jrxml` file how should i design my report ?

```
public class TestReport 
{
 public void runReport(String fileName, String outFileName) 
 {
  try 
  {
   List<R> list = new ArrayList<R>(5);

   Map parameters = new HashMap();
   list.add(new R("a1" ,"a2"));
   list.add(new R("b1" ,"b2"));
   list.add(new R("c1" ,"c2"));
     /*parameters.put("my_name", "faisal khan");
     parameters.put("my_addr", "address comes here");*/
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport( fileName, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
            JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(
            JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,outFileName);
            exporter.setParameter(
            JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, outFileName);
            print = null;
            exporter = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 private class R{
  private String name;
  private String addr;

  public R(String name, String addr) {
   super();
   this.name = name;
   this.addr = addr;
  }
  public String getName() {
   return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name;
  }
  public String getAddr() {
   return addr;
  }
  public void setAddr(String addr) {
   this.addr = addr;
  }

 }
  public static void main(String args[]){
   new TestReport().runReport("/home/faisalloe/ireports/report1.jasper", "/home/faisalloe/ireports/report1.pdf");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make use of the JasperDatasource for collections: [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html)

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport( fileName, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
```

Your report will repeat once for each element. Or you can define a subreport depending the main report, wich is to be repeated once per list element.

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but it has a high Google rank: 
  Inside a report you can use an expression for a subreport/table:
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F_COLLECTION);
Hopefully that saves someone a little frustration messing with nested reports.

Comment: Also, for those who want to see some good samples, I found this useful: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html